# getting FindFailed issue in sikuli for image on windows server 2019 (ADO VM)

Tags: selenium, azure-pipelines, ui-automation, sikuli

Getting below error when running script on window server 2019 (ADO VM) through pipeline , same script is working fine on windows 10 (having resolution 1920X1080).

I am using screen resolution utility to change the VM resolution to 1920X1080 in pipeline.
I am setup the path Bundle Folder by using below text:

ImagePath.setBundleFolder(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/SikuliImages"));

using below code

ImagePath.setBundleFolder(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/SikuliImages"));
System.out.println("Image Bundle Path="+ImagePath.getBundlePath());

```
           Screen screen=new Screen();
           String UserName_Image_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/SikuliImages/UserName_TextBox.png";
           String UserPassword_Image_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/SikuliImages/UserPassword_TextBox.png";
           String SignIn_Image_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/SikuliImages/SignIn_Button.png";
           
           Pattern  P_UserName = new Pattern(UserName_Image_Path);
           Pattern  P_UserPassword = new Pattern(UserPassword_Image_Path);
           Pattern  P_SignIn = new Pattern(SignIn_Image_Path);
                        
           System.out.println("Wait for popup");
         

            screen.wait(P_UserName,30);
            Match UserName_Found = screen.exists(UserName_Image_Path);                      
            UserName_Found.highlight(2);
            screen.type(P_UserName,UserName);
            Match UserPassword_Found = screen.exists(UserPassword_Image_Path);  
            UserPassword_Found.highlight(2);
            screen.type(P_UserPassword,UserPassword);
            Match SignIn_Found = screen.exists(SignIn_Image_Path);  
            SignIn_Found.highlight(2);
            screen.click(P_SignIn);
```

FindFailed : C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.200.2_work\1\s\Automation/SikuliImages/UserName_TextBox.png: (378x54) in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0)
Line 2226, in file Region.java

Could someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid windows path since it contains both \ and /